# Просмотр информации по сертификатам

Tags: python, ssl, openssl

На вывод необходимо получить всю информацию из ssl сертификата (subject, issuer, extensions и т д).
С сертификатами форматов pem, der разобрался, но не могу найти решение для `.jks`, `.cacert`.
Нужно сделать на **питоне**. Что имею сейчас:

```py
def get_info(path_to_file, filename, file_type):
    with open(path_to_file + "/" + filename, 'rb') as cert_file:
        if file_type == '.der':
            cert = x509.load_der_x509_certificate(cert_file.read(), default_backend())
        elif file_type == '.pem' or file_type == '.cer' or file_type == '.crt':
            cert = x509.load_pem_x509_certificate(cert_file.read(), default_backend())

        cryptography.hazmat.primitives.serialization.pkcs12.load_pkcs12(cert_file.read(), None)
            cert = cert.cert.certificate

        print("Subject: " + str(cert.subject))
        for extension in cert.extensions:
            print(extension)
```

То есть нужен какой то аналог x509.load_der_x509_certificate, но для других форматов.
Задача в том, чтобы программно реализовать команды типа

```sh
openssl x509 -in certificate.crt -text -noout
```

Answer (score 0):

Можно воспользоваться [subprocess](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html) и выполнить команду на прямую через `openssl`

```py
import subprocess
result = subprocess.run(['openssl', 'x509', '-in', 'certificate.crt', '-text', '-noout'])
```

Данное использование выведет результат по исполнению команды. Чтобы поместить в переменную результат, необходимо вызвать `check_output` метод:

```py
import subprocess
result = subprocess.check_output(['openssl', 'x509', '-in', 'certificate.crt', '-text', '-noout'])
```

Буквально, данный метод позволяет использовать любой функционал внешней утилиты. В данном примере `openssl`

#### Как воспользоваться данной возможностью на Windows

1. Установите OpenSSl для Windows
2. Установите переменную окружения для OpenSSl
3. Воспользуйтесь командой для Python, указанной выше

Если, же вы не знаете, как работать с переменными окружения в Windows, то можете указать путь к запуску на прямую, пример

```py
import subprocess
result = subprocess.check_output(['C:\\Program Files\\OpenSSL-Win64\\bin\\openssl', 'x509', '-in', 'client.crt', '-text', '-noout'])
```

Опробовано на Windows 10 Pro, 64 bit

Comment: На винде эти команды не работают

Comment: @ttraceroute работают, при правильном подходе. То, что у вас open ssl работает на windows можно указать в самом вопросе, поскольку это информация в данном случае важна. На Windows установлен openssl?

Comment: @ttraceroute добавил в ответ описание возможности для windows